# Getting the highest id value in Realm JS

Tags: realm, react-native

I need to get the highest id value that was inserted into Realm as Primary Key. I understand that using filters can give a list of values,

```
let hondas = realm.objects('Car').filtered('id');
```

So how do I get the highest `id` from the table, say at the 0th position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.Collection.html#sorted

```
let hondas = realm.objects('Car').sorted('id', true);
let highestId = hondas[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.Collection.html#max

```
let hondas = realm.objects('Car').max('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finds maximum id in realm database and increment one if no such userid is present in DB. here is the code..........

```
var l_SettingId = realm.objects(------).max("Id");
                    if(l_SettingId == null)
                    {
                      l_SettingId = 1;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                      l_SettingId + 1; 

                    }
```

"------", you can add your **SCHEMA name**.